# How do I sort a multi-dimensional array by time values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm doing a school project and I have a multi-dimensional array having `start_time` and `end_time` of courses.

I already sorted the array by day, but I also want to sort the array by time. Such that the lowest start_time is the first element of the array.

This is how my array is at the moment:

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
                     [courseID] => comp345
                     [lectureID] => ss
                     [day] => monday
                     [stime] => 18:20 
                     [etime] => 20:30 
                     [term] => winter 
                     [year] => 2014 
              )
       [1] => Array ( 
                     [courseID] => comp275 
                     [lectureID] => gg 
                     [day] => monday 
                     [stime] => 12:15 
                     [etime] => 15:16 
                     [term] => winter 
                     [year] => 2014
              )
)
```

I was wondering if there are any pre-defined functions to do that or if i need to create a new specific function for this task .

I can access the values of the start_time like this :

```
foreach ($array as $element)
{
  $start_time = (substr($element['stime'], 0, 5));
}
```

This will return the time in this format : 08:20

It works the same way as normal numbers when comparing such as :

08:20 < 10:15 = true

08:20 > 10:15 = false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the `stime` items, convert them to a timestamp and sort, sorting the original array on that:

**All versions**:

```
array_multisort(array_map(function($v) {
                              return strtotime($v['stime']);
                          }, $array), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

**PHP >= 5.5.0**:

```
array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', array_column($array, 'stime')), SORT_ASC, $array);
```

**Alternate**:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  $stime[$k] = strtotime($v['stime']);
}
array_multisort($stime, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Comment: array_multisort(array_map('strtotime', array_column($MondayArray, 'stime')), SORT_ASC, $MondayArray);  - Works - Thanks a lot , I'll accept answer after 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

Add the unix timestamp with [`mktime`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to your array and sort by that timestamp. The unix timestamp is the number of second since 1970, so it  is an integer and hence easy to sort.

Take a look at this [reference question about sorting in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php).

As you have

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [courseID] => comp345 [lectureID] => ss 
                 [day] => monday 
                 [stime] => 18:20 
                 [etime] => 20:30 
                 [term] => winter 
                 [year] => 2014 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [courseID] => comp275 [lectureID] => gg 
                 [day] => monday [stime] => 12:15 
                 [etime] => 15:16 [term] => winter 
                 [year] => 2014 ) )
```

Something like this should do it:

```
Go through array, add 'unixtimestamp' = mktime($el['hour'], $el['minute'], 0, 0, 0, $el['year'])

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['unixtimestamp'] - $b['unixtimestamp'];
}

usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');
```